# How can I determine the last line of "while read line"?

Tags: bash

How can I determine the last line of "while read line"?

for example:

```
    while read line; do
       if [ "$line" = "last line" ]; then
           echo "this line is the last one ($line);"
       else
           echo "$line"
       fi

    done <<< "$lines"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem here if you have input that is not predictable (e.g. manual input). Unless you can tell the future you can't trivially (i.e. via the `while read line` construct) know what is next to last. Also, since the loop stops when input stops, you will have to store a certain line and act on it *after* its "turn in the loop". Not before then can you know if it was the last one. If the input is a fixed string or file, it is more of a theoretical consideration than a practical one.

A prototype for doing what you want:

```
unset lastline
while read line; do
    if ! [ -z "$lastline" ]; then
        echo "$lastline"
    fi
    lastline=$line
done <<< "$lines"
echo "This is the last one: $lastline"
```

- `unset lastline` is just to "protect you" if you run the same script in e.g. a terminal multiple times, since `$lastline` then might not be empty to begin with. You could also clear it after the last `echo` if this might be an issue.
- `! [ -z "$lastline" ]` returns true if the `$lastline` variable is non-empty (technically if the length of the string is not zero). See `man test` if you are not used to these tests.

(Though my gut wants to ask you [what you really are trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :-) .)